# Can Sprinklr track Social Media > Organic Search > Website?

Tags: analytics, tracking, social-media, reporting, monitoring

Just wanted to ask, anyone can generally give an idea how tools like Sprinklr works to track omnichannel user? By using cookies to set unique visitor id? (like AA)

E.g. Case 1: User login to FB > leave comment on Company A > clicked a referrer link on FB > landing to Company A website > logged into account and exploring > send email to the company by using registered email account in website

Is this whole journey trackable? But seems I didn't find the cookies sent to somewhere to "sprinkle.com" etc. from websites and social media.

Case 2: User login to FB > leave comment on Company A > made a search in Google > Clicked a organic search result > lands to Company A website > logged in and explore

Above case, can the whole channels be tracked? Social Media > Organic Search > Website If yes, what's the technology used in tracking?